# importing only few type from one xsd to another

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

The question here is – is it possible to import subset of types from an xsd?

Consider following example :
A.xsd contains three type a,b,c
And B.xsd contains two types d,e.

When I import A.xsd in B.xsd  like following :

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.abc.com/schema/aaa" schemaLocation="A.xsd"/>
```

I get all three types –a,b and c.  I just want type a in B.xsd . I want to exclude type b and c in the xsd. Is it possible to do that ? If yes what are the options ?

Thanks
PC

Comment: I have never seen that and I ask myself for what this can be good for. Some kind type replacement insteed of override?

Comment: If you just want type A, you could extend type ns1:a into a local type.

Comment: Thanks for input Petru and Micheal. The scenario I am dealing with is a soap based webservice using spring-ws . It is importing another xsd which has defined some types. Good part is , I can reuse complex types defined in A.xsd. Bad part is.. I am getting extra types in my final wsdl which are not needed. So this is the reason I was looking if it is possible to import only subset of schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do it. But why would you want to? Surplus unused types surely do no harm?

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase @Michael, `No you can't do it.` If you're interested in some spec reading, [this is where](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#layer2) it is described.

As to why would someone want to do it, I can provide an example that I see often. I make no claim that it applies to your scenario, yet it should help those wondering why.

It all starts with what most people expect from schema: to validate exactly what they want, and no more. The mind set is then to assume that if XML is schema valid, there is none or little validation left do be done in the code behind. This is probably the reason one can see so many questions, even here on SO, that deal with all sorts of validation scenarios that seems to push what people want to do with XSD.

What I run into pretty often is people that build themselves or reference (e.g. industry standard) these elaborate type hierarchies and substitution groups, to realize that while it makes sense to have them like that in an enterprise model, concerned with an end-to-end view, individual systems within the enterprise only support a subset of that type hierarchy.

When XSDs are authored to follow certain patterns for *open content* (through abstract elements or abstract typed elements), then a schema that includes these extra types or elements is subject to pass validation of content having an xsi:type referencing the wrong type or using the wrong member of the substitution group.

To illustrate, consider a base abstract type `Address`; concrete addresses: Canadian, US, Mexico, UK. E.g. using a UK address instead of Canadian/US/Mexico is invalid for a particular business service.

In your case, assuming type `a` has no dependencies on `b` and/or  `c`, the only way to do it is to split **A.xsd** into **A'** with `a` and **A''** with the rest, and then reference **A'** in your **B.xsd**. There are ways to do this automatically, so the overhead from a maintenance perspective can be very low; when done through automatic XML Schema Refactoring (XSR), then future releases of **A.xsd** (I assume is something that's not yours) can easily be integrated with the rest of your solution.

Comment: xs:redefine is a horrible monster, but it is often used for the scenario Petru describes: you can redefine something in an included schema document so that UK addresses become invalid.